# communication between 2 fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

framentA calls fragmentB via an mother activity. FragmentA is no longer in memory. FragmentB calls fragmentA(go back to previous screen). FragmentB has some data to share with FragmentA. But, how?

here is what I tried:
static variable - it worked, but a bad habit, I can not use it
viewModel - each fragment creates it's OWN instance of view model. Therefore the 2 instances of the viewModel will not work.
DB - not a good pattern. Therefore I cant use it.

Comment: A pretty common pattern here is to have shared view model scoped to containing activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to store the fragments in Fragment Manager, when you do that you are basically trying to maintain a back stack of your fragments:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//or FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                     .add(FragmentToBeAdded, "textRelatedtoFragment")
                     .addToBackStack(null)
                     .commit();
```

Adding to the backstack helps in saving the state of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

For Fragment Navigation use: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started
It will greatly simplify your in-app navigation.

For passing parameters between Fragments/Activities:

- First solution is to use `ViewModel` with scoping of Activity using `by activityViewModels()`. Read More here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide This will give you an indirect way of passing arguments.
- Use SafeArgs (part of Navigation component) to directly pass needed data.
  More information can be found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#ensure_type-safety_by_using_safe_args